# Testing Flutter iOS app with multiple main_<env>.dart in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, environment, testflight

I am a newbie to mobile progamming. I am developing a free iOS app in Flutter and my code is ready to be tested on my DEV/Test environment before I deploy to AppStore (Prod environment). Each of these environments connects to different backend APIs, and they have different Firebase configurations.

So, I have created three `main.dart` files, namely `main_dev`, `main_test`, `main_prod.dart`. `main.dart` does not have the `void main()` function but it contains common code to be shared.

I am using flavors and the target path argument to run the respective environment locally. Eg. `flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart` and similarly for Test environment.

Xcode: I have created Schemes in Xcode that point to each flavor. I have set up the configurations, Firebase Run script to copy the correct `GoogleService-Info.plist` before each build, and I tested them locally for both DEV and Test environment.

However, I want to install my apps on my friends' mobile devices and test them in the Test environment. I tried to use **TestFlight** where I uploaded my archive from the `test` scheme. For `test` flavor/scheme, `main_test.dart` should be called. I don't find an option to pass the argument `-t lib/main_test.dart` in Xcode/TestFlight. How can I achieve this?

Is there a way in TestFlight where I can upload and test my code to connect to *Test* configurations and when I release them to the App Store, connect to *Prod* configurations.

Your answers would be really helpful for a newbie like me! Thanks!

Comment: For TestFlight, I would suggest that you label the logos of the app based on the config so that it is easier to differentiate them. You cannot upload code to Testflight.

If you have set up your schemes properly, it should pick the corresponding `main_<env>.dart` file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding the logos of the app. That's a great idea.

So are you saying that based on the scheme that I provide, it picks the `main_<env>.dart` accordingly? That's fascinating then. So, I don't have to provide `-t lib/main_<env>.dart` argument correct?

Comment: HI, were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 6):

Select `Runner` ->

Navigate to `BuildSettings` ->

Search for `FLUTTER_TARGET` and define your files there.

[image]